# How to show product total price calculation in Magento cart

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I'm having problems trying to show the product full total price in Magento, and by product total price I mean full product price without the discount; the price has to be multiplied for each product quantity added to the cart, and custom options additional price should be added as well. Which files should I edit in Magento? is it possible to show the product discount inside the cart (amount that varies with the amount of ordered products)? 
Thanks

Edit:

[image: screenshot]

In the blue rectangle it shows the regular price, which should be regular price X 2 (since product quantity is 2) with added 122€ as chosen in product special options. Instead now it shows regular price with discount applied and for only 1 product, without special option added.

Answer (score 1):

The product page will only ever show the how much a single product costs, but this will include customisations to that product as you select them (if they cost anything).  The cart will show a price for a single productm but also show a subtotal being the cost of whatever quantity you have selected at whatever price that product was (be there a discount or none).

The long and short of it is this should all happen out of the box, if you are not seeing it it's probably due to customisations to your store.

Comment: By default on the cart Magento will show the cost of the product with customisations etc for a quantity of 1 in the 'unit price' column, and then in the 'subtotal' column this unit price multiplied by the quantity you have chosen.  If you are not seeing this then I would suggest that you have changes in place in your store to change what is displayed.

Comment: as default Magento does not show the "complete subtotal price", the only thing you can display is the product price plus customization, but only for one product. If you add more than one product quantity the subtotal does not change. what I'm trying to show is a subtotal that includes the amount of custom options with the cost of the product for more than one product quantity

Comment: we managed to display unit price and subtotal (not the way we wanted but at least now it is understandable for clients), but there is still a problem with the discount: is it possible to show the product discount inside the cart (amount that varies with the amount of ordered products)?

Comment: Again, works out of the box.  If in doubt, try these things on a clean install - you should find them all to work.

Comment: on a magento clean install I can't see the discount column inside the cart

Comment: If you are talking about  discount code then no you don't see a discount column, you see the discount in the totals area according to the relevant discount code.

Comment: is it somehow possible to show the discount value on each product in the cart?

Comment: No because a discount can use complex rules involving multiple, or no specific products and so the discount may not be directly applicable to a specific product.